# AVplayer not playing specific link

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Using a very simple implementation of AVPlayer:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:self.currentCollateral.url];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.player = player;
[player play];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this link won't play:

https://www.screencast.com/users/DoorAndHardware/folders/2016%20Orlando%20Conference/media/08848a5a-d414-4bdd-861f-95cf9890d1a1/embed\

[image: Player not playing]

Not sure what I am missing.  Code works for other links.  Can't seem to find anything relevant in the documentation.  Thanks for any help!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL does not link to a media file (`.mp4` for instance) but to an embeded player.

You can see the [used URL](https://content.screencast.com/users/DoorAndHardware/folders/2016%20Orlando%20Conference/media/08848a5a-d414-4bdd-861f-95cf9890d1a1/DHI-Webstream-h264_x264.mp4) if you have a look on the source code of the linked player site. This URL should work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Before start playing to any video on avplayer we need to check whether given URL is ready to play or not. Add below observer on avplayer.

```
 [avplayerObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

#pragma Observer for Player status.
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == _audioPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
                [_audioPlayer play];

        } else if (_audioPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
        [_audioPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
    }

}
```